# Access column of matrix without creating copy of data, using Armadillo library

Tags: c++, armadillo

I have a (data/storage) class with a member `arma::mat` (a matrix), and I want to access just one column of this matrix (`arma::colvec`), but I don't want to create a copy of the data in the column. Is there any way of achieving this?

My first try was using `.col(i)`, but this returns a temporary, so taking a reference doesn't work.

Using `.colptr(i)` doesn't create a copy, but it also returns a `double*` instead of a `vec`, so it makes my life a bit hard.

```
struct Data
{
    mat A;

    /* constructors etc. */

    // reference to temporary (this is bad)
    const vec& getColumn(const uint i) { return A.col(i); }

    // doesn't create a copy, but doesn't return a vec either
    const double* getColumn2(const uint i) const { return A.colptr(i); }
}
```

The reason for wanting this is that the class has both vectors and matrices, and I want to make uniform getter and setter methods that access either one of the vectors, or a column in a matrix, depending on an index (for iteration purposes).

An example:

```
struct Data
{
    mat A;
    vec b;

    // getter
    const vec& operator()(const uint i) const
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            return b;
        }
        else if (i == 1)
        {
            // return first column of A
        }
        // etc.
    }

    // setter
    vec& operator()(const uint i)
    {
        // similar to above
    }
}
```

---

### Solution

Based on the [answer by zauguin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35984246/1850917) I found the following way to achieve the wanted functionality:

```
struct Data
{
    mat A;
    vec b;

    // getter
    subview_col<mat::elem_type> operator()(const uint i)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            return b.col(0);
        }
        else if (i > 0 && i < (1 + A.n_cols()))
        {
            return A.col(i - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            // should probably do some error checking here
        }
    }

    // setter
    vec& operator()(const uint i)
    {
        // same as the above, but without consts in declaration
    }
}
```

This returns `subview_col<mat::elem_type>` instead of `vec`, but the functionality is similar/identical for my purposes. I am not sure of the performance impact of using `.col(0)` on a `vec`, but I'm not that worried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In arma, A.col(i) doesn't return a reference, but a temporary. You can return this temporary to get reference semantics. With C++14, just write

```
    auto getColumn(const uint i) { return A.col(i); }
```

Otherwise, you have to return the proxy type, it is

```
    subview_col<mat::elem_type> getColumn(const uint i) { return A.col(i); }
```

If you have to return a `vec` instead of a `subview_col<...>`, you can use `A.unsafe_col(i)`, but you have to be sure, that you don't try to use it, after the lifetime of `A` ended. [see here](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat)

Comment: I guess I don't actually have to return a `vec`. For the second part of my question I have to do `return b.col(0)` to return a `subview_col<mat::elem_type>`, even if `b` is a colvec, but I guess that is okay.

Comment: Using `A.unsafe_col(i)` returns copy, which I can't return a reference to without storing it. But I found a solution based on your answer, so I've accepted it, and added the solution to my question.